# cannot print all elements in collection although count is positive

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I can get positive count of elements in collection ...

```
var collection;

collection = db.collection("allCodes");

collection.count(function(err, count) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("There are " + count + " records.");
});
```

... with output:

```
Connected to Database ok
There are 354 records.
```

... but can not get elements in this collection:

```
collection.find().each(function(err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("each doc");
  console.log(doc);
});
```

... it prints nothing. I am new in mongodb. So what I do wrong? I want to print all elements in `allCodes` collection.

**Update**: all code that inserts data then gets count and then tries to fetch data itself, but nothing comes out.

```
var MongoClient, collection;

MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var objectToInsert = [{
    'a': 1
}, {
    'a': 2
}, {
    'b': 3
}]
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test", function(err, db) {
    console.log("Connected to Database");
    collection = db.collection("test2");
    // clear collection -------------------------------
    collection.remove(function(err, result) {
        // insert ------------------------------------
        collection.insert(objectToInsert, function(docs) {
            // count - ok -----------------------------------
            collection.count(function(err, count) {

                console.log("Count: " + count);
                // find - fail - no objects printed -----------------------
                collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
                    console.log("Printing docs from Array");
                    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                        console.log("Doc from array");
                        console.log(doc);
                    });
                });
                db.close();

            });

        });
    });
});
```

It has output:

```
Connected to Database
Count: 3
```

So why I have only count. Where is my data?

Comment: TypeError: Object #<Cursor> has no method 'forEach'

Comment: Yea... my mistake - I guess the nodejs implementation does have an `each()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing your connection to the database before the `find` gets a chance to complete.

Move the `db.close()` call inside the callback of `toArray` like this:

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log("Printing docs from Array");
    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log("Doc from array");
        console.log(doc);
    });
    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Disclaimer**: I am not familiar with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) at all.

From the [example in the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each), it seems that you are required to create a cursor object first and only afterwards iterate over the results. I'm not sure what considerations there are for chaining commands.

```
var cursor = collection.find();

// Execute the each command, triggers for each document
cursor.each( function( err, item ) {
  console.log( "each doc" );
});
```

Comment: I tried split my chain as you advised, but the same result: empty console.

Comment: Where exactly are you executing this code? Do you have a console available at all? Also, are you sure that your cursor object that is returned is valid?